# Apache can not prevent from downloading a specific file extension (Microsoft Word .docx)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory at the root of my website named "files". I want to prevent clients from downloading any file that exists in this directory. I made a .htaccess file at the root and used the `RedirectMatch` directive as follows:

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/files.*$
```

It works good and the client can not access the directory and all the files inside it except a file that has a **.docx** extension. For this extension the file is still downloadable by the client and I don't know why. I tried many other extensions such as .zip, .pdf, .jpg also some unknown extensions such as .doca, .docy. for all of them access is denied, but for **.docx** not.
I also tried some other apache's directives such as `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` and the problem is still remained.

My apache version is 2.4.

Comment: Do you have any other redirects/rewrites, that do something specifically with .docx files?

Comment: @CBroe No, nothing.

Comment: @CBroe Does it work in your apache server?(Is the specified extension denied?)

Comment: I would suspect that you downloaded that file once prior to implementing your restriction. And that you are now simply looking at a client side cached file. Open your browsers network console and check that. Or look into your servers access log file. Or simply test with a fresh anonymous browser window, which you should _always_ do when testing web stuff.

Comment: @arkascha, Excellent, That was the problem. many thanks for your help.